# How do I redirect anonymous users to the login?

Tags: 8, rules

I'm using rules module with drupal 8 in order to redirect anonymous users to the login page after registration form submission, so I created a rule with react on event "After saving new user `(rules_entity_insert:user)`" because my account creation settings are : "Visitors, but administrator approval is required"

[image]
**Events:** After saving new user (rules_entity_insert:user)

**Conditions:**
User has role(s) - Parameter: User: @user.current_user_context:current_user, Roles: anonymous user

**Actions:** Page redirect - Parameter: URL: user/login

But its giving : WSOD with warning

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in Drupal\Core\Field\WidgetBase->extractFormValues() (line 366 of /var/www/html/D8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php).
```

Any suggestion where i am missing something.

Comment: whats the point of redirecting them to login page if `administrator approval is required`?

Comment: On this point After submitting registration form user is not logged in automatically. Still behave as "anonymous user "

Comment: yeah and if they try to login they will not be able to until they get approved. So why send them to the login page when they can't login?

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat for your time, But this is the requirement what i have to fulfill. SO i just want to know what's the data selector to check current user role using rules ?

Comment: `this is the requirement what i have to fulfill` fair enough.

Comment: I hesitate to post this as a real answer (already), but the "**AND***" value within "Match roles" (which is NOT a required field ...) looks extremely suspicious to me. So I wonder what result you'd get if you omit that "AND" (or maybe give it some more thought to enter a more appropriate value. PS to @NoSssweat : you're right in your comment(s), but that's not the question, right? Also, what if there is some watch duty service available for admins to approve/reject requests within X secs after the request is created?

Comment: All I get is `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.` when trying to put anything in the `user has role condition`. I guess its Alpha for a reason.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens all I was trying to do is make him realize that **perhaps** doing that wasn't the best choice. But if it's out of his control, then fair enough.

Comment: @NoSssweat: fully agree with you on that. But, the customer is always right ... if if the customer is wrong, correct??? Anyway, IMO [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) for D8 is not stable enough, which is also why I'm not surprised about such WSODs. What's your experience with rules usability in D8?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens my experience is that it is not usable. It's like trying to play with a broken toy that doesn't work.

Comment: @NoSssweat : thanks for confirming my impression also. For what it's worth: even though D8 is officially released some months ago, for me D8 will be production ready only when there is a stable Rules release. With that, for me "Rules for D8" is similar to "Views for D7" (I bet I'm not the only one) ... Would be nice if Rules would be in D9 core (or maybe even D8.x), no?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens yeah, I totally agree.